# Windows shell string operations (changing backslash to slash)

Tags: windows, shell, backslash

I need to write a script that takes the current path (%~dp0), transforms backslashes into forward slashes and passes it further to some command.

Due to the environment I'm working in the only option that I have is windows shell (not Powershell where the issue would not a problem).

Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `set` command has a substitution feature:

```
set a=C:\test\dir
set a=%a:\=/%
echo %a%
```

Results in:

```
C:/test/dir
```

Comment: Sweet! That's exactly what I was looking for! short and sweet and to the point :)

Comment: @den : Could you explain how to replace more complex strings as "v=1.0.0" with "v=1.0.1"?